# FLutter - how to share text over image

Tags: flutter, image, share

How can I share text with image in flutter. I want to put text over the image and share this image. I have checked many packages and most of them outdated

Answer (score 1):

For one part of your question:

> I want to put text over the image

Did you try?

[Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

As per the document:

A widget that positions its children relative to the edges of its box.
This class is useful if you want to overlap several children in a simple way, for example having some text and an image, overlaid with a gradient and a button attached to the bottom.

Example:

```
 SizedBox(
  width: 250,
  height: 250,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      Container(
       Your image 
        ),
        child: const Text(
          'Foreground Text',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```